# How display article from category and show it in block

Tags: drupal-7

I have created a content type which has some fields, and I want these fields to be displayed as a block.

I need to display some article like 5 articles from category called sport news only.

How can I do that in drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Views
https://drupal.org/node/1960048
Then create a new view as a block.